# My IF formula that is conditional on date is not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an IF formula in Google Sheets that first check Column B and if it says "Yes", Column P says "Delivered", but if it does not say Yes it checks to see if the timestamp is from over 5 days ago. If the timestamp is over 5 days ago, it displays "Not Delivered", but if it is from under 5 days ago, it displays "Pending". But this is not working, as you can see from Row 4, where the Column B does not say Yes, and the timestamp is from over 5 days ago. This should say "Not Delivered" but it says "Pending" instead. This formula works perfectly in Excel so I have no idea why it is not working in Google Sheets.

The formula (for P2) is: 
`=IF(B2="Yes","Delivered",IF(D2<TODAY()-5,"Not Delivered","Pending"))`

Comment: Maybe in Google Sheets `5` means something different.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following formula can help you

```
= IF (B2 = "Yes"; "Delivered"; IF (D2 <TODAY () - 5; "Not Delivered"; IF (B2 = "No"; "Not Delivered"; IF (D2> = TODAY () - 5; "Pending")))))
```

You can also use the following formula in cell P1

```
= {"Status"; ARRAYFORMULA (IF (D2: D = ""; ""; IF (B2: B = "Yes"; "Delivered"; IF (D2: D <TODAY () - 5; "Not Delivered" ; IF (B2: B = "No"; "Not Delivered"; IF (D2: D> = TODAY () - 5; "Pending"))))))}
```

And later delete all formulas from P2

Sidney

Comment: This brings up #ERROR!

Comment: In my case has no error, see the link!   [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LUpb03ZGtkKEvvs0tdcT7WEZCAnkEG-RFSt2mNUZbk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I managed to solve my issue by changing the date format - it was not formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

The date column was not formatted correctly, so the IF formula did not recognise it as a date